# What is the value of $0.01\log_{10}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I am trying to understand what it means by $0.01\log_{10}$, which was published in [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1268220/) at page 7 in IEEE. I cannot convert $0.01\log_{10}$ to a number since I expected to see something like $0.01\log_{10}^3$ to be able to say it is equal to 0.0048. The authors uses this expression twice in the paper.

Could someone kindly help me in understanding what the authors meant by $0.01\log_{10}$?

The following is a snapshot of the paragraph of the paper in which $0.01\log_{10}$ was used.

[image]

Comment: Maybe relevant: $0.1 \log_{10}(x)$ is a function of $x$. So you may need to figure out what data is being plugged into the log function.

Comment: And $0.0230$ is not a value that you are expecting? ($\log$ may mean $\ln$).

Comment: @jdods to be exact 0.01log10(x),10 is  the base.

Comment: Sounds like it is "within 0.01 on a $\log_{10}$ scale", which is basically like giving a percent error (the error is at worst a multiplicative factor of $10^{0.01}$).

Comment: It's not obvious to me why the authors should use $0.01\log_{10}$ instead of a simple number. They used this expression twice in the paper.

Comment: must be an internal terminology to signal processing people. it's 1/2000 of a dB

Answer (score 2):

In context, I believe that "within $0.01 \log_{10}$" is shorthand for "within $0.01$ on a $\log_{10}$ scale". This is the same as saying that the two numbers differ by at most a multiplicative factor of $10^{0.01}$. So it is basically a fancy way of saying that the error is at most $2.3\%$. Such language would make sense in a field where things are commonly measured in log scales, such as acoustics.

Comment: The parameter that the authors suggested being within $0.01\log_{10}$ is the regularization parameter that should be much less than $1$, e.g., $0.01$, whereas $10^{0.01} = 1.023$

Comment: @AFP Note that I said a *multiplicative factor*. If the actual number is 0.01 and your error is a multiplicative factor of $10^{0.01}$ then your actual error is something like $0.00023$.